# Jmeter Time vs Threads report doesn't show aggregated result from all machines

Tags: jmeter, distributed-testing

Running a JMeter distributed test on 10 machines, every machine with 25 users. While checking the report generated in the *Time Vs Threads* graph in the Response Times section it shows number of active threads 25. Actually it is showing 25 threads from every machine. I would expect it show max 250 threads and aggregate graph instead of plotting 10 points.
Can someone help how we can get aggregate graph for all threads.
Thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are generating report from the system it is running. You need to consolidate all the reports from the system and then generate the graph using [merge results](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/)

Now, if your setup consist of one master and other machines as slaves then slaves machines should send the listener data to master.
Check below link:-
https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#sendermode

Try with master and slave for two machines, initially, and do consider the below info:-

> Make sure that all the nodes (client and servers) :
>
> are running exactly the same version of JMeter. are using the same
> version of Java on all systems. Using different versions of Java may
> work but is discouraged. have a valid keystore for RMI over SSL, or
> you have disabled the use of SSL.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, we are using master slave combination. In the plan we have added Active Threads Over Time Listener and file path we have added path to save the report. But after run we cannot get any report saved on slave machines. We get only one report on the Master machine. Also the report is not showing aggregate threads over time. It shows parallel threads on all machines over time. So if we are running 25 threads on 3 machines, it shows max 25 threads in graph whereas we expect it to show 75. Is there any way to achieve this. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [__machineName()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineName) or [__machineIP()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineIP) function so it would be possible to distinguish the results coming from different machines and properly calculate the concurrency.

More information:

- [Active Threads Over Time Listener](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/)
- [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction/)

Comment: While using Active Threads over Time listener it plots threads from individual slaves. e.g When I am running test with 25 users then it plots graph of 25 threads against time and plots threads from every slave in different color. Basically we want to get sum of threads from all machines plotted vs time. So with 2 machines with 25 users we expect to get 50 threads in graph instead of showing 25-25 overlapped with max 25 threads. Is there any such listener or a way which sum ups all users from all slaves? Thanks for your details.